# How to import Excel data to Swift Codable

Tags: swift, excel, codable

I'm trying to import data from an Excel sheet and store them in an array of objects. How can I do that in Swift ?

For example if I have this table:

[image]

And I would like to store them in an array of this object

```
struct User: Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var Name: String
    var Number: Int
    var Code: Int
    var Area: String
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This might help you: [Easy parsing of Excel spreadsheet format with Swift's Codable protocols](https://desiatov.com/swift-codable-xlsx/)